# How do I validate characters a user types into a WinForms textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, validation

What code should I write to prevent any special characters except '_' (underscore) while entering the name in text box?

If such character exist then a popup message should appear.

Comment: Provide the code you wrote: we are not going to do everything for you...

Comment: I was wondering why there was such a harsh reaction to a reasonable question and then I saw that it originally started out, literally, with "plz send the code"...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rather than me writing the code for you, here are the basic steps required for accomplishing such a feat:

1. Handle the `KeyDown` event for your `TextBox` control.
2. Use something like the [`Char.IsSymbol` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00k2wda1.aspx) to verify whether or not the character that they typed is allowed. Make sure you check explicitly for the underscore, because you want to allow it as a special case of other symbols.
3. If a valid character is typed, do nothing. WinForms will take care of inserting it into the textbox.

   However, if an invalid character is typed, you need to show the user a message, informing them that the character is not accepted by the textbox. A couple of things to do here:

   1. Set the [`e.SuppressKeyPress` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress.aspx) to True. This will prevent the character from appearing in the textbox.
   2. Display a tooltip window on the textbox, indicating that the character the user typed is not accepted by the textbox and informing them what characters *are* considered valid input.
      The easiest way to do this is using the [`ToolTip` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx). Add this control to your form at design time, and display it when appropriate using one of the overloads of the [`Show` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.show.aspx).
      In particular, you'll want to use one of the overloads that allows you to specify an `IWin32Window` to associate the tooltip with (this is your textbox control).

      [image: An example of a balloon-style tooltip, displaying an error message.]

      Alternatively, instead of a tooltip, you can display a little error icon next to the textbox control, informing the user that their last input was invalid. This is easy to implement using an [`ErrorProvider` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx). Add it to your form at design time, just like the tooltip control, and call the [`SetError` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.seterror.aspx) at run-time to display an error message.

      [image: An example of an ErrorProvider control, set on a text box.]

      Whatever you do, do *not* display a message box! That disrupts the user trying to type, and it's likely that they'll inadvertently dismiss it by typing the next letter they wanted to type.

Comment: Very nice answer. I like the fact that it explains all of the good design you need to incorporate to make it a good user experience, especially the advice about message boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler to the `TextBox`'s `KeyDown` event. You can examine which key was pressed there, and do whatever you want with it, including popping up a message box.

Comment: he wrote _entering the name_... do you think he wanted to say _text_? I didn't answer because I really didn't realize what he was asking.. and special thanks to @Raj More to edit this post because it was unreadable beforfe

Comment: @Marco: I'm not sure I follow. He wrote *entering the name **in** the text box.* Perhaps the TextBox holds a user's name. I'm not sure but that doesn't seem important to the question. Am I missing something?